# NGINX pretty url rewrite - get value of parameter and rewrite to value page

Tags: redirect, nginx, indexing, parameters, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite domain.tld/index.php?a=value to domain.tld/value

For example

domain.tld/index.php?a=contact to domain.tld/contact

domain.tld/index.php?a=latest to domain.tld/latest

and so on...

Any ideas how to do it?

The Apache rules are as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
rewrite ^/(\w+)$ /index.php?a=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(\w+)+\/$ /index.php?a=$1&q=$3 last;
```